# flutter firestore: how to get a query of documents

Tags: flutter, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get a list of user objects from firestore through a query. My current attempt looks like this:

```
List<User> getDiscoveryUsers(
    String userId,
  ) async {
    Query<Object?> query =
        userCollection.where('finishedOnboarding', isEqualTo: true).limit(10);

    var collection = await query.get();
    //get the users list from query snapshot
    var users = collection.docs.map((doc) => User.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();

    return users;
  }
```

However I am getting the error:

```
Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'.
Try fixing the return type of the function, or removing the modifier 'async' from the function body.
```

I know there are a few similar questions on stack overflow, but i just cant seem to get this to work. Anyone know whats going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the return type of your function from `List<User>` to `Future<List<User>>`.

Happy coding:)

Comment: If i change the return to a future, how do i convert the future to List<User> when the function is called?

Comment: Just use await infront of function call. `final user = await getDiscoveryUsers('<userId>');`

Answer (score 1):

your return type should be **Future** and must wait with **await** when running query on firestore.

```
Future<List<User>> getDiscoveryUsers(
    String userId,
  ) async {
    Query<Object?> query =
        userCollection.where('finishedOnboarding', isEqualTo: true).limit(10);

    var collection = await query.get();
    //get the users list from query snapshot
    var users = collection.docs.map((doc) => User.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();

    return users;
  }
```